# C++ Construct to check whether a local expression is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++20, sfinae, c++-concepts

I'm looking for some construct that can detect whether a local expression is a constant expression, or whether it's not, that can be used in a `static_assert` declaration.

In code:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int i = 1;
    if constexpr(i) {}  
    static_assert(is_constexpr(i));

    int j = 1;
    //if constexpr(j) {}  // error: 'j' is not usable in a constant expression
    static_assert(!is_constexpr(j));
}
```

The `is_constexpr` here can be a macro, a class (then probably with other syntax), or a function. How to make `is_constexpr(i)` return `true/true_type` and, conversely, `is_constexpr(j)` return `false/false_type`?

I tried a lot of the solutions available here on SO (also using old-school SFINAE) without success. I can edit in the links and my failed attempts if required.

[Playground on godbolt here](https://godbolt.org/z/15aP8b5Gn)

Comment: What is the usecase?

Comment: @Enlico: long story. Basically template metaprogramming which should do things differently (return different types) if they can be done at compile time.

Comment: Parameters like `t` are never `constexpr`.

Comment: This doesn't make sense for arbitrary expressions, since non-type template parameters (of concepts) can only receive constexpr values. Instead, the concept has to be something like `given T, is T::value constexpr`.

Comment: The question is _why_ do you want this? Why is `if constexpr()` not sufficient? What's the use-case?

Comment: I'm importing the duplicate question into a more related one.

Comment: @康桓瑋: sure, I've checked these, but they're not applicable, as they do not incorporate local variables. Look, e.g., at the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm voting reopen as none of the duplicates fix the issue, which is "check if a local variable is **NOT** contexpr"

Comment: I've also edited the question to make it realistic. You cannot check if something is not constexpr in an if constexpr context, so if you really want that, you're screwed. (Or trying to solve the underlying problem the wrong way)

Comment: @JHBonarius: thanks for your efforts, that probably expresses the intent better. With regard to `static_assert` vs. `if constexpr`: both have exactly the same [requirements since C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert), namely "an expression contextually converted to bool where the conversion is a constant expression".

Comment: @davidhigh C++23 is not released yet, but anyhow I get where you are going. That raises an issue...

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that parameters (like `t`) are not *constant expressions*. For example, we cannot use `t` as a template non-type parameter, or as a size of a built-in array.

This means that some expression say `some_expr( t )` that contains(involves) the subexpression `t` is itself not a constant expression, either.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, the question is too narrowly posed. But I can use those constant expressions directly `main()` -- quest ion is rather how to identitfy whether I can apply `if constexpr`. I'll do an edit.

Comment: @davidhigh In your edited question you're able to use the statement `static_assert(is_constexpr(i))` inside `main` only because inside the concept `CONSTEXPR` you're not using the parameter `t`. Note that inside the body you're just using `true` which does not involve/use the parameter `t`. On the other hand, if you were to use `t`, the program will fail to compile for the reason explained above in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Can `is_constexpr` be a function?

The simple fact that you write `is_constexpr(i)` means that you're looking for a function of type `bool(auto)`; but you also want to be able to pass it `constexpr` arguments or non-`constexpr` arguments, so for sure it can't be `consteval` otherwise it would error when called in the latter scenario; so you can at most make it `constexpr`. However, there's no such a thing (yet?) as a `constexpr` function parameter, so as soon as you pass something to that `constexpr` function you have no way to detect whether or not the argument was a constant expression at the call site.

### Can `is_constexpr` be a meta-function?

The other opportunity would be to use a metafunction, but how would you expect to call it? If you expect `is_constexpr<i>`, i.e. passing the entity you are querying as a template argument, that would be clearly only possible if `i` is `constexpr`; if you go for `is_constexpr<decltype(x)>`, you are expecting that `decltype(x)` contains some info about the `constexpr`-ness of `x`, but that's not the case, as `constexpr`/`consteval` are not part of the type of an expression.

### Do you really need it?

This, I believe, means that whenever you ask whether an expression is a constant expression, you can always find the answer by looking at the code before that expression, and that answer will not depend on any boolean condition, not even a `constexpr` condition.

In other words, **I believe (and happy to be proved wrong)**, there's no way for an expression appearing in a C++ program to be `constexpr` or not in the same line of code depending on the path that leads there.

### Do we really have a usecase?

I agree that this is likely an XY problem.

So I challenge you to write an example where a given C++ expression of your choice appearing at a certain line of code is `constexpr` across one branch of execution and non-`constexpr` across another branch. And the branches can also be compile-time (well, given your question, you were not asking about non-compile-time branching, so in the previous sentence you can *<s>can also be</s> are*).

Comment: If you pass a parameter to a consteval function, it has to be a constant expression, so that might give a possibility?

Comment: I follow your discussion why it's likely not possible -- I was hoping for a combination of, say, a macro and SFINAE or the like, but maybe you can't work around the basic problem (--"a non-constant expression can't be used as non-type template parameter"). The usecase is there ... think about an if consteval but one which returns *different types* ... I know that it's not common and basically violates ODR, but there are usecases.

Comment: One example: consider the algorithm std::set_intersection. If one could at compile time identify that two vector references actually are identical objects (using constexpr std::addressof, say), one could simply exit the algorithm and return an empty range. Clear, you can figure out by looking at the code that they are identical, you'd say, but when one writes a library which should be usable also by  non C++ experts, you probably shouldn't forward this tasks to your users.